# Call shared library from Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a problem about ruby Interop with a shared library.

When i use this code:

```
module mymodule
  extend DL::Importer
  dlload './lib.so'
  extern 'int Open(int my_id, int size, int creat)'
end
```

The int type is not recognized in the ruby context. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t specify the parameter names in your `extern` call, just the types:

```
extern 'int Open(int, int, int)'
```

Comment: thanks but now i have this other problem:/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/dl/func.rb:55:in `call': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/dl/func.rb:55:in `call'
        from test.rb:13:in `CloseMemoryMapped'
        from test.rb:34:in `CallProcess'
        from test.rb:45:in `<main>'

Comment: i can't declare a variable outside of begin--> end block?

Comment: in this scenario   begin
 my_id = 1  #random_id
 size = 2048
 creat = 1
 id = 1
 id = puts Tesuto.Open(my_id,size,creat)
 
  rescue
 pass()
  ensure
 puts Tesuto.Close(id)
  end

Comment: It’s tricky to see what’s going on without formatting, but it looks like the problem could be `id = puts Tesuto...`. `puts` returns nil, so you’re reassigning `id` and end up passing nil to `Tesuto.Close(id)`.

Comment: ruby is very strange:   extern 'char* Read(int,int,char*)'  Why i can't receive the correct string from c++ context?